# What are callwith and samewith supposed to do?

Tags: raku

What are `callwith` and `samewith` supposed to do? I thought `callwith` was supposed to run a subroutine of the same name of the current subroutine, but using the arguments I pass to it.

From the docs:

> [`callwith` calls the next matching candidate with arguments provided
>   by users and returns that candidate's return value.](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#sub_callsame)

To me it sounds like inside the two-arity `MAIN` subroutine (i.e. `MAIN($a,$b)`) that `callwith($x)` would call `MAIN($x)`.

But it doesn't:

```
multi MAIN ($a, $b) {
    my $result = callwith("$a$b");
    say "Got $result from MAIN(\$a)";
}

multi MAIN ($x)    {
    say "Hello $x";
    return True;
}
```

> ```
> $ perl6 callwith.p6 foo bar
> Use of uninitialized value $result of type Any in string context.
> Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
>   in sub MAIN at callwith.p6 line 3
> Got  from MAIN($a)
> ```

Then this definition of `samewith` makes it sound like calling `samewith($x)` from inside of the two-arity `MAIN` (i.g. `MAIN($a, $b)`) would try to call the two-arity `MAIN` again ("current candidate", right?).

> [`samewith` calls current candidate again with arguments provided by
>   users and returns return value of the new instance of current
>   candidate.](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#sub_samewith)

But it actually calls the one-arity `MAIN`:

```
multi MAIN ($a, $b) {
    my $result = samewith("$a$b");
    say "Got $result from MAIN(\$a)";
}

multi MAIN ($x) {
    say "Hello $x";
    return True;
}
```

> ```
> $ perl6 samewith.p6 foo bar
> Hello foobar
> Got True from MAIN($a)
> ```

So am I seeing correct behavior by `callwith` and `samewith`? If so, what am I misunderstanding? I'll gladly update the documentation once I understand this issue better.

I'm using Rakudo-Star-2018.01 on CentOS 7.4.1708.

Comment: `callwith` reuses the dispatcher, while `samewith` redispatches.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you are seeing is correct.

From [But here's my dispatch, so callwith Maybe](https://rakudo.party/post/Perl6-But-Heres-My-Dispatch-So-Callwith-Maybe) by Zoffix:

> samewith — make the same call from scratch, *following a new dispatch
>   chain*, with these new arguments, and come back

Zoffix also mentioned that if using one of the `next____` or `call_____` functions (e.g. `nextwith` or `callwith`), any previously rejected candidates will not be reconsidered.

So, it sounds like the signature* (or capture) is already fixed before using `callwith`. `samewith` gets around this because it "redispatches" "from scratch" (Thanks Brad Gilbert for your comments, and Zoffix for your blog).

If you need to change the signature used (or capture), use `samewith` or just use the subroutine name again (`MAIN` in this case).

*I originally called this "arity", but "signature" or "capture" are better terms (thanks @jjmerelo and @Tinmarino for pointing me to these terms).

Comment: In a more general sense, you probably mean  [signature](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature) and not arity, right?

Comment: In a more specific sense, you probably mean [capture](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Capture) ;-)

Comment: The issue still bothers me as a Raku learner now in 2023. I have made some experiments and then understood what's going on. The documentation for `samewith` has been corrected to say "samewith calls the multi again with arguments provided at the call site and returns the value provided by the call." But Raku runtime should not have kept silent and just skip the line of `callwith` when it cannot find an appropriate candidate to call.

Comment: @AlvaPan If you don't understand why, perhaps ask about it in a question here on StackOverflow? (i.e. Why does the Raku runtime keep silent and skip "callwith" when it can't find an appropriate candidate to call it?). If I were still using Raku for work, I'd spend the time to figure it out, but I'm mostly using R, Bash, and some Python (for bioinformatics) nowadays. I sure miss programming in Raku (all the builtin functions that I don't have to remember which library or package they're housed in).