# Callwith not calling other candidates? What are "other candidates"? Is it exhausting the list of other candidates? Is that list available?

Tags: raku, dispatch

I'm trying to address [this issue](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1904), which was actually raised by [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698773/what-are-callwith-and-samewith-supposed-to-do) related to the different behavior of [`callwith`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#index-entry-dispatch_callwith) and [`samewith`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#sub_samewith). The latter seems to be clearly defined, however, it's not so clear with `callwith`.

Check out this example:

```perl6
proto how-many(|) {*}

multi sub how-many( Pair $a, Pair $b ) {
    say "Int $a and $b";
    return "There are $a and $b"

}
multi sub how-many( $a, $b ) {
    say "Not int $a and $b";
    my $calling = callwith( 1 => $a, 2 => $b );
    return $calling;
}

say how-many( "little piggie","littler piggie" );
```

According to the documentation, `callwith` should call the next matching candidate. However, this is the output:

```perl6
Not int little piggie and littler piggie
(Any)
```

So it's calling the second version of `how-many`, then calling a non-existing function (apparently) and returning `Nil`, which is passed as `Any` to the calling routine.

I have also tried with using different signatures, but that does not work either. The example in the documentation apparently indicates that it will work only if the variables belong to the same class hierarchy. Is that the case? It might not be, since changing the positional signature to `Any $a, Any $b` does not work either, neither changing the order of declaration.

> Above, changing `callwith` with `samewith` will obviously work, but I'm trying to understand how `callwith` works, not make the code above work.

Besides, it seems to be going *down* the class hierarchy, but not up. This [example in roast](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/d1baf2e7a3e56cd6619c46040d04ed6daebc1d02/S06-multi/redispatch.t#L38-L42), the Perl 6 test suite, works:

```perl6
my $tracker = '';
multi d($x)     { $tracker ~= 'Any' ~ $x };
multi d(Int $x) { $tracker ~= 'Int'; callwith($x+1); $tracker ~= 'Int' };
lives-ok { d(3) }, 'can call callwith inside a multi sub';
```

However, if we change it so that the we use `callwith` from the bottom of the hierarchy like this:

```perl6
my $tracker = '';
multi d($x)      { $tracker ~= 'Any' ~ callwith( "called-with" => $x) };
multi d(Pair $x) { $tracker ~= "Pair $x" };

say d( 3 );
```

It fails with

```perl6
Use of Nil in string context in sub d at rewrite-test-callwith.p6 line 6
```

Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of `callwith`, `nextwith`, `callsame`, and `nextsame` walk through the set of candidates **determined by the original arguments**. Thus while `callwith` can be used to replace an argument, that's all it is doing. It is not going to cause a change in the pre-determined list of candidates to iterate through.

Consider these three candidates:

```
multi foo(Any $x)  { say "In Any case with $x" }
multi foo(Real $x) { say "In Real case with $x"; callwith($x.Int); }
multi foo(Int $x)  { say "In Int case with $x"; callsame(); }
```

We can ask which candidates apply using `.cando` and passing it a `Capture`. Thus:

```
.say for &foo.cando(\(42));
```

Will produce the following output:

```
sub foo (Int $x) { #`(Sub|78402328) ... }
sub foo (Real $x) { #`(Sub|78412816) ... }
sub foo ($x) { #`(Sub|78412968) ... }
```

Since all 3 candidates match. Calling `foo(42)` will result in the following output:

```
In Int case with 42
In Real case with 42
In Any case with 42
```

By contrast, with:

```
.say for &foo.cando(\(4.2));
```

The output is:

```
sub foo (Real $x) { #`(Sub|78412816) ... }
sub foo ($x) { #`(Sub|78412968) ... }
```

And calling `foo(4.2)` has the `callwith` iterate through those candidates:

```
In Real case with 4.2
In Any case with 4
```

A `callwith` or similar in the most general candidate will not have any effect, and will evaluate to `Nil`.

While the example here is with multi subs, the same applies to wrappers and non-multi methods, which also walk a predetermined list.

Finally, it's also worth observing that if there was a fresh dispatch every time, the example I gave would end up as an infinite recursion. By walking the pre-determined candidate list, that can never happen.

Note that none of this applies to `samewith`, which exists precisely to do a completely fresh dispatch.